# To show that $\sum_{a=1}^{p-2}(a(a+1)/p)=-1$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

Let $p$ be an odd prime and for any integer $a$ , relatively prime to $p$ , let $(a/p)$ denote the Legendre symbol . Then how to show that $\sum_{a=1}^{p-2}(a(a+1)/p)=-1$ ?

I know that $\sum_{a=1}^{p-1}(a/p)=0$ , so it is enough to show that modulo $p$ , the integers $a(a+1) ; a=1,...,p-2$ runs through a complete set of non-zero residues modulo $p$ except exactly one quadratic residue mod $p$ . But I am unable to show this . Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that
$$ \newcommand{\kron}[2]{\left( \frac{#1}{#2} \right)}$$
$$ \sum_{1 \leq a \leq p-2} \kron{a(a+1)}{p} = \sum_{1 \leq a \leq p-2} \kron{a^2}{p} \kron{1 + a^{-1}}{p} = \sum_{1 \leq a \leq p-2} \kron{1 + a^{-1}}{p}.$$
We are pivotally using that every nonzero element has an inverse mod $p$.

As $a$ runs through $1$ to $p-2$, its inverse $a^{-1}$ also runs through the inverses of every element except for $p-1 = -1$. Thus
$$ \sum_{1 \leq a \leq p-2} \kron{1 + a^{-1}}{p} = \sum_{1 \leq b \leq p-2} \kron{1 +b}{p} = \sum_{2 \leq c \leq p-1} \kron{c}{p}.$$
This last sum is only missing $\kron{1}{p}$ from being a complete sum over the finite field. Since we know that
$$ \sum_{1 \leq x \leq p-1} \kron{x}{p} = 0,$$
we have that
$$ \kron{1}{p} + \sum_{2 \leq c \leq p-1} \kron{c}{p} = 1 + \sum_{2 \leq c \leq p-1} \kron{c}{p} = 0 \implies \sum_{2 \leq c \leq p-1} \kron{c}{p} = -1,$$
as we set out to show. $\diamondsuit$

Comment: I didn't realize you have already written a solution . Mine is same as yours

Comment: No problem, and good work! Perhaps sometime in the future someone will benefit from both versions of the answer. It's surprising how useful even small changes in point of view can ultimately prove. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Ah , I think I got it .

For every $1\le a \le p-1 , \exists $ unique $1\le a' \le p-1$ such that $aa'\equiv 1(mod \space p) $ . Now for $1 \le a \le p-2$ , gcd$(p.a(a+1))=1$

So for $1\le a \le p-2$ ,

$(a(a+1)/p))=(a(a+aa')/p)=(a^2(1+a')/p)=(a^2/p)((1+a')/p)=((1+a')/p)$ ,

and since $p-1$ is the inverse of itself modulo $p$ , so for $1\le a \le p-2$ , the distinct inverses $a'$ run through the residue system $\{1,...,p-2\}$ . Hence

$\sum_{a=1}^{p-2}(a(a+1)/p)=\sum_{a'=1}^{p-2}((a'+1)/p)=\sum_{m=2}^{p-1}(m/p)=0-(1/p)=-1$